# C++, Constructors: Out-of-line definition of 'class' does not match any declaration in 'class'

Tags: c++, xcode

So I was trying to program a target heart rate calculator in C++ and when I tried to build it, this error was returned. Just to let you know, I am instructed to separate the implementation and interface.

Here's the interface

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class HeartRates
{
public:
// constructor initialize HeartRates
HeartRates( std::string, std::string, int, int, int );

// Setting each variable
void setFirstName( std::string );
void setLastName( std::string );
void setdobMonth( int );
void setdobDay( int );
void setdobYear( int );
void setCurrentYear( int );

std::string getFirstName() const;
std::string getLastName() const;
int getdobMonth() const;
int getdobDay() const;
int getdobYear() const;
int getCYear() const;

int getAge() const;
int getMaximumHeartRate() const;
int getTargetHeartRate() const;


private:
std::string firstName;
std::string lastName;
int dobMonth;
int dobDay;
int dobYear;
int currentYear;
};
```

And here's the implementation

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "HeartRates.h"

using namespace std;

// constructor that initializes all the stuff
```

This is the line that is giving me this error: Out-of-line definition of 'HeartRates' does not match any declaration in 'HeartRates'

```
HeartRates::HeartRates( string first, string last, int M, int D, int Y, int cY )
{
    setFirstName( first );
    setLastName( last );
    setdobMonth( M );
    setdobDay( D );
    setdobYear( Y );
    setCurrentYear( cY );
}
```

Continue on with the code

```
// set functions
void HeartRates::setFirstName( string first )
{
    firstName = first; // store the first name in the object
}


void HeartRates::setLastName( string last )
{
    lastName = last; // store the last name in the object
}

void HeartRates::setdobMonth( int M )
{
    dobMonth = M; // store the month of birth in the object
}

void HeartRates::setdobDay( int D )
{
    dobDay = D; // store the day of birth in the object
}

void HeartRates::setdobYear( int Y )
{
    dobYear = Y; // store the year of birth in the object
}

void HeartRates::setCurrentYear( int cY )
{
    currentYear = cY;
}



// get functions
string HeartRates::getFirstName() const
{
    return firstName; // return user's first name
}

string HeartRates::getLastName() const
{
    return lastName; // return user's last name
}

int HeartRates::getdobMonth() const
{
    return dobMonth;
}

int HeartRates::getdobDay() const
{
    return dobDay;
}

int HeartRates::getdobYear() const
{
    return dobYear;
}

int HeartRates::getCYear() const
{
    return currentYear;
}



// Functions
int HeartRates::getAge() const
{
     int age;
    age = currentYear-dobYear;
   return age;
}


int HeartRates::getMaximumHeartRate() const
{
    int maxHeartRate;
    maxHeartRate = 220 - getAge();
    return maxHeartRate;
}

int HeartRates::getTargetHeartRate() const
{
    int targetHeartRate;
    targetHeartRate = getMaximumHeartRate() * 0.85;
    return targetHeartRate;
}
```

Sorry for the formatting and copy and pasting everything. Newbie here, I just don't know which part of the code went wrong.

Comment: You have 2 strings and 3 ints in the interface definition, but you have 2 strings and 4 ints in your implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
HeartRates( std::string, std::string, int, int, int );
```

2 strings and 3 int.

```
HeartRates::HeartRates( string first, string last, int M, int D, int Y, int cY )
```

2 strings and 4 int.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue today and my fix was slightly different, so I'll throw this here in case it ever helps anyone in the future. I had forward declared a class OUTSIDE of the appropriate namespace in the header, so my error looked something like this:

```
1. Type of 1st parameter of member declaration does not match definition
'const std::shared_ptr<MyClass> &' (aka 'const shared_ptr<MyClass> &') vs
'const std::shared_ptr<MyClass> &' (aka 'const shared_ptr<myNamespace::MyClass> &'))
```

The solution for me was to forward declare that class inside the namespace, rather than outside it.

Bad:

```
class MyClass;

namespace myNamespace {

}
```

Good:

```
namespace myNamespace {

class MyClass;

}
```